# The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID, but only on Android usig chrome

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

I'm getting an error with GSI saying

> The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID

However it's only happening on Android. I have no idea why this is. Any ideas?

In Chrome on Windows and Mac it works fine. I've searched all over Google and read the documentation carefully through to find a solution for this, but so far I'm stuck.

```js
async function initClient() {
  await google.accounts.id.initialize({
    auto_select: true,
    referrerPolicy: {
      policy: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin'
    }
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    callback: creds => initTokenClient(creds)

  });
  google.accounts.id.prompt();
  google.accounts.id.renderButton(
    document.getElementById("buttonDiv"), {
      locale: "en"
    }
  );
}

function initTokenClient(creds) {
  client = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
    client_id: CLIENT_ID,
    referrerPolicy: {
      policy: 'strict-origin-when-cross-origin'
    }
    scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly \
                    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
    callback: (res) => checkAuth(res)
  });
  getToken();
}

function checkAuth(res) {
  if (res !== undefined) {
    access_token = res.access_token;
    listUpcomingEvents();
  } else {
    console.log("Could not auth");
  }
}

function getToken() {
  client.requestAccessToken();
}

function revokeToken() {
  google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(access_token, () => {
    console.log('access token revoked')
  });
}
```